# Why can't I sometimes see the output from docker run

Tags: docker

Until now I've been used to seeing the output from a `docker run {someimage} {somecommand}` command. For example:

```
[1 ~/git/unsullied] docker run alpine ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 ps
```

However I have an image that works differently some how. For example:

```
[1 ~/git/unsullied] docker run --platform linux/amd64 myimage ps
[1 ~/git/unsullied] echo $?
0
```

So no output.

(I'm using the `--platform` to suppress the platform warning)

I can 'sort of' get the output like this:

```
[1 ~/git/unsullied] id=$(echo ps | docker run -i -a stdin --platform linux/amd64 myimage)
[1 ~/git/unsullied] docker logs $id
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 sh
    9 ?        00:00:00 bash
   12 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

But I don't understand why I need to. Can someone please enlighten me?

By the way, I don't really need the output of `ps`. That was just an example. It doesn't matter what the command is, I get no output running the 'usual' way.

In case it matters:

```
[1 ~/git/unsullied] docker version
Client:
 Version:           24.0.2-rd
 API version:       1.42 (downgraded from 1.43)
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        e63f5fa
 Built:             Fri May 26 16:40:56 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           rancher-desktop

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.6
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       9dbdbd4b6d7681bd18c897a6ba0376073c2a72ff
  Built:            Fri May 12 13:54:36 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.7.0
  GitCommit:        1fbd70374134b891f97ce19c70b6e50c7b9f4e0d
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        860f061b76bb4fc671f0f9e900f7d80ff93d4eb7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

(Responding to comment)

It's odd. Here's my original Dockerfile:

```
FROM flyway/flyway:10.4.1

RUN apt-get update; \
apt install gnupg2 wget vim lsb-release -y; \
sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'; \
curl -fsSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc|gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/postgresql.gpg; \
apt update -y; \
apt-get install postgresql-client-16 -y

ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/bash
CMD /usr/bin/bash
```

I'm basically trying to add the postgres 16 client to the 'standard' flyway image, and override the entrypoint of that image.

If however I build my own image using the [flyway Dockerfile](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker/blob/main/Dockerfile), and then add my pg16 client bits, I seem to end up with a 'normal' image.

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy as flyway

WORKDIR /flyway

ARG FLYWAY_VERSION=10.4.1
ARG FLYWAY_ARTIFACT_URL=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/

RUN curl -L ${FLYWAY_ARTIFACT_URL}${FLYWAY_VERSION}/flyway-commandline-${FLYWAY_VERSION}.tar.gz -o flyway-commandline-${FLYWAY_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && gzip -d flyway-commandline-${FLYWAY_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && tar -xf flyway-commandline-${FLYWAY_VERSION}.tar --strip-components=1 \
  && rm flyway-commandline-${FLYWAY_VERSION}.tar \
  && chmod -R a+r /flyway \
  && chmod a+x /flyway/flyway

RUN apt-get update; \
apt install gnupg2 wget vim lsb-release -y \
  && sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list' \
  && curl -fsSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc|gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/postgresql.gpg \
  && apt update -y \
  && apt-get install postgresql-client-16 -y

ENV PATH="/flyway:${PATH}"
```

I guess I don't understand how a docker image can somehow suppress output from a non-interactive command. At least that's what it seems to be doing.

Comment: Please show us the Dockerfile for `myimage`. Without that information there's no way for us to know what's going on.